# Class not showing up in run configurations?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a simple class that takes out items that were already in another array from the first array, by putting it into a list. Whenever I run this program though, another program that I created starts to run. I have tried to change the run configuration as well, but it doesn't show up on the list..? Here is the code:

```
package collections;

import java.util.*;

 public class Arraystring {

public static void main(String [ ] args, int Collection, int String){
String[] things = { "eggs", "lasers", "hats", "pie" };
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String x : things){ //enhanced for loop
    list1.add(x);
}
System.out.println(list1);

String[] thingstwo = {  "lasers", "hats" };
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0;i<list2.size(); /* size for list, length for array */ i++) //regular for loop

{
    list2.add(thingstwo[i]);

}
//print list one
for(int i = 0;i<list1.size(); /* size for list, length for array */ i++) //regular for loop
{
    System.out.println(list1.get(i)); //Use .get for lists instead of []
}




    editlist(list1, list2);
    System.out.println();
    //print list one
    for(int i = 0;i<list1.size(); /* size for list, length for array */ i++) //regular for loop
    {
        System.out.println(list1.get(i)); //Use .get for lists instead of []
    }



}
 public static void editlist(Collection<String> l1, Collection<String> l2){
    Iterator<String> it = l1.iterator(); //Goes through each list item by item
    while (it.hasNext()){
        if(l2.contains(it.next())){
            it.remove();


        }
        System.out.println(it);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Comment: in your main method you have inputs `int Collection, int String`. They have to be coming from somewhere....

Comment: Youre right! I have no idea where that came from, but after I run it I still don't get the expected output of eggs and pie, instead I get this:

Comment: eggs
lasers
hats
pie
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@2a139a55
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@2a139a55
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@2a139a55
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@2a139a55

eggs
lasers
hats
pie

Comment: What is this? Thanks so much

Comment: remove `System.out.println(it);` line (which prints that `java.util.ArrayList$Itr@2a139a55` stuff)

Comment: @ankhzet why does printing out "it" get me that stuff though? I have marked you as best answer.

Comment: Actually, when you printing some object, different from `String`, it prints return value of method `toString()`, called on that object. For example, result of `list2.toString()` will be `[lasers, hats]`. But `it` is an instance of `Iterator`, and that class has no `toString()` overridings, so it uses default `Object`'s one, which just returns the actual instance class's name (`java.util.ArrayList$Itr`), and actual to-instance reference numeric value `2a139a55`, both separated by `@` char. That is common output for classes, that not override `toString()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute `Run file` command from menu/shortcut or change `main project` in the IDE.

Specify yours IDE and proper shortcuts/commands would be given to you.

**Upd.**

You have error in yours logic:

```
String[] thingstwo = {"lasers", "hats"};
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
  list2.add(thingstwo[i]);
```

Look at it line-by-line:

```
String[] thingstwo = {"lasers", "hats"};
```

Defining array, ok.

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Defining list of strings, ok.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
```

Looping throug items of list `list2`, *not ok*. `list2` at this point is empty. Assuming you wanted to loop through `thingstwo` and add it's items to `list2`, so fixing the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thingstwo.length; i++)
```

And...

```
  list2.add(thingstwo[i]);
```

Adding `i`-th item of `thingstwo` to `list2`, ok.

Running:

```
[eggs, lasers, hats, pie]
eggs
lasers
hats
pie

eggs
pie
```